# How to get value fron mailview webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
<div class="mailview" style="margin-right:18px;">

    Dear Customer,<br><br>
    Greetings from Calling Cards!.<br><br>

    We've created a new Calling Cards account for you.
    <br><br>
    Your Authentication Code is: 125412 <br><br>
    Click the following link and enter the authentication code to activate your Account: <a href="http://domain.com/Account/CustomerActivation/bedehhhh9ab7-b016h6hf0-4h6h68bf-a9hhh68-5dbd4hh3e77d7d"> Click 

    Here </a>.

    <br>
    <br>

    Please contact us if you have any questions or need further assistance.

     <br><br>Thank you for your business with us!<br>




            </div>
```

In this I want Authentication Code , which i when click on Link(Click Here), will be able to send that code to text-box on other window ,

Is it possible , if yes , Code will be appreciated most .

Thanks in Advace !!!

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses , I am not able to figure out how to proceed ...

Answer (score 0):

Java Code for that

```
   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mailview']"));
    Pattern codePattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)(Your Authentication Code is: )(\\d+)(.*)", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = codePattern.matcher(element.getText());
    if (m.matches()) {
        String code = m.group(3);
        System.out.println(code);
    }
```

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='mailview']"}

Comment: I even try to find text using following xpath  /html/body/div/div/div/text()[3]..

Comment: Can you give the link to the webpage.Have you checked whether that element is inside a frame

Comment: I am using free mail service name as mailinator.com , html code is provided in description...I wonder what is used of element on first line of code provided by you